# Campos vacíos en metodo PUT en webservice

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy realizando pruebas de mi webservice con el framework CodeIgniter... mi problema reside en que, digamos tengo una tabla con 5 campos, de esos 5 campos solo quiero modificar 2, al realizar el GET para ver los cambios efectivamente se han realizado, solo que los otros 3 campos que no edite se actualizan como null, alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: Eli, bienvenida a SOes. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour]. Por favor revisa el articulo [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta, a fin de que puedas incluir un [mcve]. Asi podremos responder tu pregunta. De o contrario, tu pregunta podria ser mal recibida.

Comment: Excelente, gracias

Comment: Hola Eli, bienvenida a SOes, podrías colocar el codigo que tienes hasta ahora para ayudarte de mejor manera.